# 「壁の奥の対象には当たり判定は適用されない」を実装したい

Tags: unity3d

簡潔に言うと、下記の画像のような状況を実装したいです。
”自分と対象との間に障害物がある場合、対象は当たっていないとして処理する”感じです。
方法の見当もついていない状況なので、ヒントだけでもくださるとありがたいです。

[image: 参考画像]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分と対象物とを結ぶ線分（を延長するので直線と言い直して可）を求めます。
壁と当該直線との交点を求めます。この交点と自分との距離を求めます。
「交点との距離＜対象との距離」なら対象物は壁の向こう側なので「当たり判定」対象外です。
# 対象物が壁と反対側にある場合も考えるのであれば距離だけでなく方向判定も必要（こちらの詳細は今は書かないでおきます）

文言「当たり判定」ってのはこの場合おかしい（微塵も当たっていないので）「視野に入るか判定」ならわからないこともないけど。